# I am trying to change the background of a textView while TextToSpeech is running, is this possible?

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I am trying to change a textView background while textToSpeech is running.
However, my code changes the textView background after the textToSpeech is completely finished speaking.

```
 Log.i(TAG, "Inside else block of play");

            Handler mainHandler = new Handler(mAppContext.getMainLooper());

            Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
            };


            speakOut(word);

            do {
                mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
            } while (tts.isSpeaking());
```

Answer (score 0):

A cheap and easy solution is to set the textview then immediately speak out the word. The user can't notice.

EDIT: Otherwise you can always create an [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Could you give me an example of how you would use the Async Task for this situation? I am having a little trouble, I am kinda new to it.

Comment: Always google before asking a question on Stack Overflow
http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html